# SQL syntax, and c# table entry into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

I have two problems

1. mySql snytax
2. Inserting data from asp Table1 control

I have two tables User (which has UserID=1 (auto increment)) and WallPostings which has a field Wallpostings (not to confuse the two as one has capital P)

I would like to make a join so Wallpostings will know which userid its refering to and then insert the data from my Table1 control

Tables:

```
------------------
User
------------------
UserID (pk, AI)
Name
DOB
Location 
etc

-------------------
WallPostings
-------------------
UserID (pk)
Wallpostings
```

has a one to one relationship for the tables

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPostings (Wallpostings) VALUES ('"+ Table1 +"')", cn);
OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Unsure how to make the join so the same userid thats set in my User table is the same in WallPosting table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, you should have UserID in WallPostings be a foreign key of the User table so that it doesn't allow UserID's that don't exist there to enforce referential integrity.

Then in your code you don't need a join, you just need to know what the userID is when inserting the wall posting.  So that you have:

```
insert into WallPostings
(userID, WallPosting)
values
(1, 'data goes here')
```

Assumedly the user is logged into the site in some fashion so that you know what their userID is when posting or making this data modification.

Comment: That depends on how the data is listed in the table control.  You can always step through each row in the table and read the text from each cell.  I'm assuming you have textbox controls or something that the user is filling in or something like that though?

Comment: yeah atm there is no layout just a blank Table texbox and button when the user types something its fired into the table

Comment: In ASP.net every object can be read from the code behind page if it has an ID and a runat="server" parameter.  Then you could simply refer to the textbox by name e.g. txtWallPosting.Text

Comment: A table is made of HtmlTableRow's and HtmlTableCell's.  You can loop through the rows and cells to get to the appropriate cell, and you can read the innerText or innerHTML values to get the information in the cell.